# Okhttp big file upload fails

Tags: java, node.js, okhttp

I am experiencing an issue with Okhttp + Node.js Formidable serverside big file upload.
Currently the upload works for < 100Mb files but fails for bigger files.
For bigger files, the onprogress event serverside is fired until 99% progress, regardless of the file size, then it stops, reports request abort, and the onfile event is not fired.

Already tried timeouts workarounds, even defined a custom SocketFactory to manually set the socket keepalive and sotimeout.

So, Im stuck here. Any help would be appreciated.

```
CustomSocketFactory MySocketFactory = new CustomSocketFactory();

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .socketFactory(MySocketFactory)
        .readTimeout(largenumber, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(largenumber, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(largenumber, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

        .build();

RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
        .addFormDataPart("nombre_file", file_pais.getName())
        .addFormDataPart("nombre_pais", pais.getName())
        .addFormDataPart("file", file_pais.getName(),
                RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"),
                        new File(filepath)
        .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(server_url)
        .post(requestBody)
        .build();

Call call = client.newCall(request);

Response response = call.execute();
response.body().close();
```

Comment: Serverside often has a limit on how big POSTed content can be. Do you have server-side info for us? Which type of server, can you see the config, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Its way too easy using snoopy api: one line of code if you exclude identifiers definition :)

```
URI uri = ...;
Path fileToUpload = ...;
Snoopy.builder()
      .config(SnoopyConfig.defaults())
      .build()
      .post(uri)
      .followRedirects(true)
      .failIfNotSuccessfulResponse(true)
      .body(fileToUpload)
      .consumeAsString();
```

https://bitbucket.org/abuwandi/snoopy

Tested on large files and it worked like a charm